# What is the interpretation of the Null Hypothesis giving more Mean time to Survival than taking several parameters?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I was wondering what would be the interpretation if :

```
fit1<-coxph(Surv(time,status=0)~X1+X2+...Xp)
surv_fit1<-survfit(fit1)



summary(fit1)
gives the following result
time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
535  23177   18069    0.496 0.00285        0.491        0.502




survrec<-Surv(time,status=0)
survfit(formula = survrec ~ 1, type = "kaplan-meier", conf.type = "log-log")
summary(survfit)



time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
700  20572   20686    0.501 0.00246        0.496        0.506
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It is not clear what exactly you want to see.

Comment: @Dimitris Rizopoulos Why does the time at which survival probability of 50% observed on a latter date without taking any variables than the time which comes when we applied all the predictors?